# How to build if condition using ply?

Tags: python, parsing, compiler-errors, lexer, ply

I'm trying to build a simple compiler using ply. I built arithmetic and logic expressions correctly but I have some errors when running if condition. For example when I enter if(5>2) as an input for program I got `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'type'`
Samples of my code:

```
def t_IF(t):
    r'if'
    return t.value
```

```
def p_statement_expr(t):
    '''statement : expression
                | comparison
                | if_statement'''
    print(t[1])
```

```
def p_IF(t):
    '''if_statement : IF LPARENTHESES comparison RPARENTHESES'''
    t[0] = t[3]
```

```
def p_expression_comparison(t):
    '''comparison : expression GTH expression
                | expression LTH expression
                | expression GTHOREQUAL expression
                | expression LTHOREQUAL expression
                | expression EQUALEQUAL expression
                | expression NOTEQUAL expression'''

    if t[2] == '>':
        if t[1] > t[3]:
            t[0] = True
        else:
            t[0] = False

    elif t[2] == '<':
        if t[1] < t[3]:
            t[0] = True
        else:
            t[0] = False

    elif t[2] == '>=':
        if t[1] >= t[3]:
            t[0] = True
        else:
            t[0] = False

    elif t[2] == '<=':
        if t[1] <= t[3]:
            t[0] = True
        else:
            t[0] = False

    elif t[2] == '==':
        if t[1] == t[3]:
            t[0] = True
        else:
            t[0] = False

    elif t[2] == '!=':
        if t[1] != t[3]:
            t[0] = True
        else:
            t[0] = False
```

Any help would be valuable. Thank you.

Comment: In Ply, we typically use `p` as the name of the argument to a parser action function (`p_…`). `p` is a list of grammar values (or an object that acts like a list). We use `t` for the name of the argument to lexer functions (`t_…`). `t` is a token object. Using different names helps us remember that the types are different.

Comment: Yes, I'll fix this issue thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In Ply, a lexer function must always return a token object.

But here, you return a string:

```
def t_IF(t):
    r'if'
    return t.value
```

It should have been:

```
def t_IF(t):
    r'if'
    return t
```

Although you're really better off handling keywords as suggested in the [Ply manual](https://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn6) at the end of section 4.3.

Comment: Another error appears after change this:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @sahar: that will be the result of an error in some other token action, I think.

Comment: I have fixed the problem. Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate that.